# dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed

Tags: apt, dpkg

I just installed Ubuntu (12.04.4) and I upgraded to 13.10

I have no idea how to fix this :/

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-common-lts-saucy
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,718 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 175174 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-common-lts-saucy ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-saucy'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
  different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing xserver-common-lts-saucy (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-common-lts-saucy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post the output of `ls /usr/lib/xorg`.

Comment: ls /usr/lib/xorg
modules  protocol-precise.txt  protocol.txt

Comment: This helped me too.Everything is fine now.Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the below commands,

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt.bak
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The above commands rename that text file `protocol-precise.txt` to `protocol-precise.txt.bak` and fixes the dependencies.