# Can I avoid reinstalling from scratch? Upgrade failing with "dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting - with different file - not allowed

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I asked for assistance about a month ago, but haven't received a single response.  If I asked incorrectly or broke etiquette rules I am truly sorry.

My original question was this:

> I ran 12.04 LTS forever without a hitch.  Realized I was falling behind, so I took the plunge.
>
> First problem was that I had to take a phased approach; couldn't upgrade directly to 14.  But packages for 13.x were no longer available on US servers (I'm in San Diego).  I selected "Best Server", and it took me to Singapore.  All good.
>
> First upgrade I did over SSH, from my LAN.  Went from 12.04 to 13.04.  It took a few hours, but went without a hitch.  Everything tested good.
>
> Next upgrade (13.04 to 13.10) I did over SSH, from work.  Again took a few hours, but everything went smoothly.
>
> When I got home I decided to go for the gold, and kicked off the final upgrade (from 13.10 to 14.04) from the local machine.  First I changed the source from Singapore back to the US.  Then I started the upgrade.  It went well, but eventually started returning errors.  First was a minor error, which said the install would continue.  After two or three I received a message that the install failed and would be halted.  But it continued.  I noticed that the video kept turning off and on.  I allowed it to continue to completion, after a few more errors.
>
> The end state is that the host machine appears to lock as soon as it boots.  However I am able to SSH into the machine, and it appears to be functioning properly.  I believe the problem is with X-Windows.  I have an NVIDIA adapter, which I believe may be problematic with this release.  I would really like to fix this install, instead of reloading from scratch.  From the remote machine I just attempted the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```
>
> And received this error (leaving off most of the output):
>
> ```
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   xserver-common-lts-trusty
>  The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   libglamor0 libspice-server1 libxatracker2 xorg xserver-xorg
>   xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
>   xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
>   xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
>   xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
>   xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xserver-xorg-video-intel
>   xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
>   xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
>   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
>   xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
>   xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
>   xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
>   xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
>   xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
>
> Fetched 2,819 kB in 7s (369 kB/s)
> Extracting templates from packages: 100%
> (Reading database ... 382361 files and directories currently installed.)
> Removing xserver-common-lts-trusty (2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1) ...
> Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-trusty'
> dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
>   different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
> dpkg: error processing package xserver-common-lts-trusty (--remove):
>  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  xserver-common-lts-trusty
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```
>
> Is there anything I can do to get this fixed, short of starting from scratch?

Instead of restating the question I would simply like to ask; is it possible for me to fix this failed installation?  Or am I doomed to starting over?  I have the system working like I want so I really hope I don't need to reload.  But if I do, is there a recommended way to back up what I have, so I don't need to totally reinvent the wheel?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Sorry no-one answered you - I myself don't feel qualified to assist in this particular problem, but if the system is operating OK, I would be tempted not to reload the OS.  Your original query is still online, so it's not as though it has been deleted.

Comment: Failed upgrades take longer to debug then a fresh install. Do a fresh install and do not format / or /home, if you have a separate /home . Your data in /home will be preserved

Comment: Hi Charles,

Thank you so much for your comment.  Problem is that I am no longer able to install any updates; most likely due to the upgrade issues.  So the system will quickly fall out of date again.  Also I cannot logon locally, although that in itself is not a big deal.

Comment: Bodhi,

All I use this machine for is a web server, php/mysql, syslog server (capturing events from my cisco firewall), and remote access server into my internal network.  I don't really have anything in /home, but lots of configurations I would need to recreate for the above mentioned applications.  Probably small potatoes to the experts here, but it took me weeks to get it all working properly.  I guess I can find and save the configurations for each of those applications; but I'm afraid I'll forget something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rm the mentioned file and it will be ok.
Also, it's already answered [dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419304/dpkg-divert-error-rename-involves-overwriting-usr-lib-xorg-protocol-txt-wit)

Comment: Yuri thank you *so* much for your response.  I can't believe the answer was right there in front of me...all I had to do was search for the "precise" (pun intended) error I was getting!

Fyi I haven't fully tested the fix yet.  But I followed the instructions in the link you provided, and so far everything looks good.  I was able to update packages, and no errors  were reported.  All that's left is for me to restart and see if I can log in locally; I'll wait a couple days on that one!

Thanks again,
Brian

Comment: Of course I couldn't wait - went ahead and restarted the system.  Had a scare after I waited a while I couldn't connect. But I checked the console - was at a Grub Loader prompt.  Once I hit enter it displayed a couple "CIFS" errors, then loaded X with no further issues.  Only other thing I notice is when the display blanks out, it flickers.  But I can wake it back up without issues.  Thanks guys for your assistance!

-Brian