# Upgrading from Ubuntu20 to Ubuntu 22 I had a message asking me to dpkg --configure -a

Tags: package-management

Upgrading from Ubuntu20 to Ubuntu 22 I had a message asking me to dpkg --configure -a

Here is the result of this operation that is not solving the problem. It seems that i have a problem with 3 packages.
libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64
usrmerge

I have tried to sol it with dpkg --configure -f . But it did not work. What should i do next ?

```
francois@francois-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for francois: 
Setting up libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs to /usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs-gst0.10 by libgstreamer1.0-dev'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs' with
  different file '/usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs-gst0.10', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64 depends on libgstreamer1.0-dev (>= 1.16.2); however:
  Package libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so': No such file or directory

FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so /usr/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so: rc=1

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64
 usrmerge
francois@francois-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dvd+rw-tools gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 git-core hddtemp libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libaom0
  libarmadillo9 libasync-mergepoint-perl libbasicusageenvironment1 libboost-atomic1.74.0 libboost-chrono1.74.0 libboost-date-time1.74.0 libboost-serialization1.74.0 libboost-system1.67.0
  libboost-system1.74.0 libboost-test1.74.0 libboost-thread1.67.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcamel-1.2-62 libcbor0.6 libcdio18 libcfitsio8 libclang1-10 libcodec2-0.9 libdap25 libdap27 libdapclient6v5 libdc1394-22
  libdns-export1109 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdvdread7 libebml4v5 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libegl1-mesa-dev libepsilon1 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libffi7:i386 libfluidsynth2
  libfuture-perl libgdal26 libgeos-3.8.0 libgit2-28 libgles2-mesa-dev libgroupsock8 libgupnp-1.2-0 libhandy-0.0-0 libhdf5-103 libhdf5-cpp-103 libhogweed5 libhttp-parser2.9 libigdgmm11 libilmbase24
  libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl libjs-modernizr libjson-c4 libjsoncpp1 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkadm5clnt-mit11 libkadm5srv-mit11 libkdb5-9 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore
  liblaszip8 liblibreoffice-java liblinux-epoll-perl liblivemedia77 libllvm10 libllvm12 libllvm12:i386 libmatroska6v5 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmetrics-any-perl libmms0 libmozjs-68-0
  libnetcdf15 libnettle7 libntfs-3g883 libodbc1 libofa0 libopenexr24 liborcus-0.15-0 libpango-perl libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-posix2 libpdal-base13 libpdal-base9 libpdal-plugin-draco
  libpdal-plugin-e57 libpdal-plugin-faux libpdal-plugin-hdf libpdal-plugin-i3s libpdal-plugin-icebridge libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud libpdal-plugin-python libpdal-plugin-sqlite libpdal-plugins
  libpdal-util13 libpdal-util9 libperl5.30 libpgm-5.2-0 libphonenumber7 libphonon4qt5-4 libphonon4qt5-data libplacebo7 libpoppler97 libproj15 libprotobuf17 libpython2-dev libpython2.7-dev libpython3.8
  libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqgis-3d3.10.4 libqgis-analysis3.10.4 libqgis-app3.10.4 libqgis-core3.10.4 libqgis-gui3.10.4 libqgis-native3.10.4 libqgis-server3.10.4
  libqgisgrass7-3.10.4 libqgispython3.10.4 libqhull7 libqpdf26 libraw19 libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libreoffice-style-tango libridl-java libsane libsereal-perl libsnmp35
  libsrt1 libstruct-dumb-perl libtbb2 libtepl-4-0 libtest-fatal-perl libtest-metrics-any-perl libtest-refcount-perl libtinyxml2-6a libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0
  libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl libunoloader-java libusageenvironment3 libusrsctp1 libvpx6 libwebp6 libx264-155 libx265-179 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common
  libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-3 libxml-writer-perl libzip5 linux-headers-5.4.0-136 linux-headers-5.4.0-136-generic linux-image-5.4.0-136-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-136-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-136-generic lz4 mpi-default-bin odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 perl-modules-5.30 phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc python-enum34 python-olefile python-pil python-pil.imagetk
  python-roman python-sip python2-dev python2.7-dev python3-atomicwrites python3-entrypoints python3-nose python3-requests-unixsocket python3-retrying python3-simplejson python3-wcwidth python3.8
  python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal ruby2.7 tango-icon-theme ure-java x11proto-input-dev x11proto-xext-dev xfconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs to /usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs-gst0.10 by libgstreamer1.0-dev'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs' with
  different file '/usr/bin/dh_gstscancodecs-gst0.10', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64 depends on libgstreamer1.0-dev (>= 1.16.2); however:
  Package libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so': No such file or directory

FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so /usr/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so: rc=1

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:amd64
 usrmerge
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It looks like `usrmerge` is trying to merge `/opt` with `/usr/opt`, which doesn't exist. See related [Upgrade trouble 20.04 to 22.04.1 usrmerge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442133/upgrade-trouble-20-04-to-22-04-1-usrmerge) and also [Re: E: usrmerge: installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2105845#p2105845)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting \`/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with different file \`/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419304/dpkg-divert-error-rename-involves-overwriting-usr-lib-xorg-protocol-txt-wit)